# CQ5.6 - CUG enabling for protecting pages breaks other components

Tags: aem

We have implemented login functionality like geometrixx site in our existing website(with close to 700+ pages).

We want to show protected pages only to logged in user, every user who is registered gets assigned a group/ CUG lets say "listed users".

now in page hierarchy I have products page and under product page I have 8 products pages.somewhere On homepage I have a nav bar component which fetches all product children pages and shows a left nav bar with 8 entries.

If I enable CUG in a way that only "listed users" should have access to 2 out of 8 product pages, any access to direct links are redirected to login page. Which is fine.

But the  nav bar component which earlier used to show all 8 product pages now shows only 6 pages.

The main idea behind putting pages behind login is lead generation.So if non logged in users dont see the link itself where would they click to get redirected to login page and subsequently feel like registering with our site.

Requirement is that my existing nav bar should continue showing 8 links and on click of 2 protected page links, he should get login/ register option.

We are using most of things Out of the Box.

any pointers helping in how do we achieve this would be great help ? **PS**: *i have given a nav bar as one such component affected in existing site like this there could be many more components fetching their content from site hierarchy and stand chance to get broken in such case.*

Answer (score 0):

The nav bar can pick up all child pages as per page structure. That should not restrict the page title display on the nav bar.

As for the pages the access can be controlled by template level page properties by adding the 'listed users' group over there. In the jsp you can give an initial check for the user if they are a member of 'listed users' else redirect to login page

Hope that helps

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site not a forum. So it favours solid answers over chatty posts. If you meant this as a sensible answer please phrase it as such.  Please avoid asking questions of the OP in answers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The question does not affect the answer but was asked to know how current implementation was and perhaps should be put in as  a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two entities involved, JCR and Sling.By default any un-authenticated request is associated with a user called Anonymous, the JCR sessions will have ACL's associated with anonymous.

In JCR, if a user does not have access to nodes, that session will not see those nodes.We access the JCR via Sling ,by default if you don't have permission the request will result in a 404 error(because for underlying JCR session the resource does not exist). Sling can be explicitly instructed to request for authentication for specific paths.

The combination of these concepts are leveraged to create the CUG functionality. Sling is instructed to force for authentication for CUG enabled pages. The JCR is instructed to show these nodes only for users who have access.

When you directly request the product pages without login, it is sling that is redirecting you to login page. When your navigation component is looping over nodes to create the menu for anonymous users JCR is only showing it 6 pages as the other two are out of reach for anonymous.

The only* way to work around this is to make the Navigation component configurable. Instead of node iteration, the content author will have to configure the the url and page title so that the links show up for everyone.

- You can ignore the session associated with the request and use a custom JCR session that has access to all the product pages, but that would be disregarding the ACLs and you don't want to do that .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions 
Below is how we ended up doing it.
- Protect the page you want to enable CUG with proper CUG.
- Hide the page in nav.
- Create a redirect page in same hierarchy with same title as the one you wanted to protect.redirect it to your protected page.